# authentication ticket is the same for different application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I Created two apps Asp.net 4 web applications. when I create one user in first app and log in as that user, and and start another app i am logged as that user. at one app I created my own membership provider and role provider. I used Forms authentication. But that doesn't fixed my problem. Can somebody tell me why auth ticket suits two different apps and how to fix this problem?
I don't know what part of code should i show. if somebody needs some code please tell i'll show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because you didn't set a `machineKey` for the applications, hence they're both using the global `machineKey` as defined in `machine.config`.

Also, you're probably running two apps under the same hostname (possibly `localhost` with different port), so the browser is re-sending the authentication ticket stored in the cookie to both apps.

In each app `Web.Config`, try to set a different `machineKey`:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="1C4AF0D197F076CD6F6DBB14AB0A2D8D21D686040E829F3B1DC8B3A75011C5B9E7CA0AF3E56083F818A0B48E1C2358E2C4183B1D638C5F0C668591951A41B9A2" decryptionKey="2D41E8D77838F5EBBC0ACD1E8EC267379A109EF0B89CA8B229E35D13B0871705" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```

I used [MachineKey Generator](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey) to generate the above key.

Comment: Is mashine.config some Windows file? How should I change my mashineKey

Comment: It is stored globally in system folder. But you shouldn't change it, you need to set different `machineKey` for each app or have them running on different hostnames.

Comment: I tried to do so and i got such an error:Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: Are you using Virtual Directory in IIS?

Comment: When you run your app, what's the URL?

Answer (score 2):

If the two applications are hosted on the same machine, they are likely using the same cookie to store the Authentication Ticket on the browser.  If you do not change the cookie name, the default is `.ASPXAUTH`.  If you want each application to store it's own Authentication Ticket separately, you need to change the cookie name for one or both of the applications.

In your Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".AppNameAuth"  />
</authentication>
```

I usually change it to `.AppNameAuth`, replacing `AppName` with the application's name.